# Google Data Studio Scatter chart. System error

Tags: google-analytics

{@DaImTo said this question was off-topic. I agree with him. But my question was somehow rejected on the official community forum. So I posted it here.}

I cannot create a scatter plot chart. The following is my datasource. It is very simple.

```
type, time, byte
a, 600, 100
b, 610, 90
c, 620, 80
```

I set up dimention and X,Y axis config then I got a system error. (Internal server error)

```
Dimention = type
X = time
Y = byte
```

I can create other types of chart like bar charts, line charts, tables and score. Only scatter plot does not work?
Can you share any advices or examples?
I found this example but it did not work after I copied it in my google drive.. https://analytics.googleblog.com/2016/08/data-exploration-with-google-data-studio.html

Btw, I posted this question to the official community but somehow this post was deleted.. (I posted it again but it was deleted as well)

---

Update 1

I found a great example. But still I cannot show up the scatter chart on my own data studio.
https://analytics.googleblog.com/2016/08/data-exploration-with-google-data-studio.html

What I did...

```
1) Copy the sample Google Sheet data into my google drive.
2) Copy the sample Data studio into my google drive. 1)'s data was used as a datastore.
3) Open the copied data studio file but the chart does not show. The dimention and X,Y axes were not set.
4) I tried to set the config (dimention=Kind of business, X=YoY Change, Y=Expenses) But I got system error (Internal Error)
```

How can I show up the scatter chart?

Other two charts, bar chart and table, are displayed properly.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: I know what you say. I tried to find the support page or email address on Google DataStudio but I could not find it. So I posted it here since I have no place to go.